# Mount shared Ubuntuone folder

Tags: ubuntu-one, mount, fstab, shared-folders

Is it possible to mount a folder, which is shared by another person into my Ubuntu-One folder (or any other) to my Ubuntu system (not the Web-interface). It also would be nice to do this via fstab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu One's file sync service is synchronization, and not remote file storage. This means the client will download everything in a folder to the machine you choose to synchronize that folder to, rather than creating a mount point to a remote server.

If you've accepted a share from someone, you can open the Ubuntu One control panel and in the `Folders` tab of the interface, the folders which are shared to you will be listed. You can simply check the folder in question to enable synchronizing it to your computer, and all the files in that folder that was shared to you, will start downloading.